# Android - Google Maps Grey Screen on Signed APK

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps

I have a pretty simple Android app that uses Google Maps API to display a map with a few pins.

When I run the project on my device through Eclipse, everything is working fine. However, when I export a signed APK and install this on my device through Google Play store, I get only a gray screen in place of the map.

I'm not getting any errors in LogCat, so I don't know where to begin debugging. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Do you have both your debug and your release signing keys set up with your Maps V2 API key?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the date and time in the smartphone is correct.

Comment: This answer would be more suited as a comment.

Comment: @KyleT Sorry, i'm noob here and i need 50 of reputation to add a comment.